How to predict time series?
I have the precipitation of twelve months (t=1,2,...,12) as below.
o = {30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 70, 50, 40, 30};


I have estimated the rainfall using this formula.
j = 1;
n = 3;
T = 12;
No = Length[o];


etpcom = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[o], i++, 
  etpcom = AppendTo[etpcom, Mean[o] + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(n\)]\((SetAccuracy[
\*FractionBox[\(2\), \(12\)] \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
              1\), \(No\)]\((o[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]*Cos[
\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]*j\), \(T\)]*i])\)\), 4]*Cos[
\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]*j\), \(T\)]*i] + SetAccuracy[
\*FractionBox[\(2\), \(12\)] \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
              1\), \(No\)]\((o[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]*Sin[
\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]*j\), \(T\)]*i])\)\), 4]*Sin[
\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]*j\), \(T\)]*i])\)\)]];


How can I change or write a command to make predictions using this relationship for the following months (t=13,14,...).


(1) Use Fitted Model to Forecast Time Series, (2) Using TimeSeriesForecast for forecasting the traffic growth, (3) Build a Model for Forecasting Stock Prices.

Also, please edit the question and include your Mathematica code instead of a screenshot of the code.

The math code was inserted.

Thanks for your comment, but these instructions are ready. I want to use the relation mentioned above.

Instead of For[i = 1, i <= Length[o] simply write For[i = 1, i <= 50?

You have data for a single year with a phenomenon that is cyclic (rainfall).  I see that you've included some sine and cosine terms but no unknown parameters and no error structure.  So with no unknown parameters and no defined error structure how to you expect to obtain prediction intervals?  And is the use of SetAccuracy necessary?

Thank you for your answer, my question is the same, how to change the above command (what parameters or commands to add) so that I can make a prediction.

Without giving any other background (and, of course, the numbers you give aren't real rainfall amounts) a reasonable prediction for months 13, 14, and 15 are the values for months 1, 2, and 3.  You have described no basis for any prediction error bands.

Let's use the example from help pages of Predict Neat Examples  and just take your data without using yours formula:
dataset = {30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 70, 50, 40, 30}; 
data = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, dataset];

visualizePrediction[data_, method_] := Module[
{p, predictionplot, dataplot, xs},
dataplot = 
ListPlot[List @@@ data, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {"Data"}];
xs = data[[All, 1]];
p = Predict[data, Method -> method];
predictionplot = Plot[{
  p[x],
  p[x] + StandardDeviation[p[x, "Distribution"]], 
  p[x] - StandardDeviation[p[x, "Distribution"]]
  }, {x, Min[xs], Max[xs] + 4}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Gray, Gray}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {3}}, Exclusions -> False, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 PlotLegends -> {"Prediction", "Confidence Interval"}];
Show[predictionplot, dataplot, PlotLabel -> method, 
ImageSize -> 500]]; 

p = Predict[data, Method -> "GaussianProcess"]; Table[p[x], {x, 12, 16, 1}](*Predict with next 13,14,15,16 months*)

visualizePrediction[data, "GaussianProcess"]


UPDATE 25.12.2024
Using ChatGPT:
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"]
o = {30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 70, 50, 40, 30};
fun[o_List, x_Integer] := With[{
    n = 3,
    T = 12,
    No = Length[o]
    }, 
Mean[o] + 
Sum[SetAccuracy[(2/12)*
     Sum[o[[i]]*Cos[((2*Pi*j)/T)*i], {i, 1, No}], 4]*
   Cos[((2*Pi*j)/T)*x] + 
  SetAccuracy[(2/12)*Sum[o[[i]]*Sin[((2*Pi*j)/T)*i], {i, 1,No}], 
    4]*Sin[((2*Pi*j)/T)*x], {j, 1, n}]];
fun[___] := Missing[]

f = Table[fun[o, x], {x, 1, 15, 1}];

lenData = Length[o];
lenF = Length[f];

(*Calculation of residuals (prediction errors) for common data*)
residuals = Take[f, lenData] - o;

(*Calculation of the standard deviation of the residuals*)
stdDev = StandardDeviation[residuals];

(*Confidence level-95% (critical value from normal distribution)*)
z = 1.96;

(*Determining the upper and lower confidence intervals*)
upperBound = f + z*stdDev;
lowerBound = f - z*stdDev;

ListLinePlot[{o, f, upperBound, lowerBound }, 
PlotLegends -> {"data", "Prediction", "Upper confidenceinterval", "Bottom
confidence interval"}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Gray, Gray}, ImageSize -> 500] 



Yes, this obtains a prediction but how does one justify such a process that involves an annual cyclic nature?  The predictions for months 16 and on are all just the mean of the data.  This is not a criticism of your attempt but rather of that Mathematica makes such easily misused functions available without proper guidance. and necessary details.

@JimB .I agree with you 100%.

Change your code to a function:
Clear[fun];
fun[o_List, x_Integer] := With[{
    n = 3,
    T = 12,
    No = Length[o]
    }, Mean[o] + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(n\)]\((SetAccuracy[
\*FractionBox[\(2\), \(12\)] \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(No\)]\((o[\([i]\)]*Cos[
\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]*j\), \(T\)]*i])\)\), 4]*Cos[
\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]*j\), \(T\)]*x] + SetAccuracy[
\*FractionBox[\(2\), \(12\)] \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(No\)]\((o[\([i]\)]*Sin[
\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]*j\), \(T\)]*i])\)\), 4]*Sin[
\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]*j\), \(T\)]*x])\)\)];
fun[___] := Missing[]

In[71]:= res = Table[fun[o, x], {x, 1, 15, 1}]

Out[71]= {30.8, 37.6, 51.12, 61.4, 67.8, 79.7, 94.2, 94.0, 73.88,
50.2, 37.2, 32.0, 30.8, 37.6, 51.12}


